# How do I allocate 2D array of char array contiguously in memory and write to file in single call

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc, contiguous

Here I come with my new C question, I have an array of char arrays and I want to reserve memory contiguously in memory to helps write into file with a single call.

ok, that's what I have:

```
#define PACKET_SIZE 40960
#define BUFFER_SIZE 3950
#define N_BUFFERS 4

typedef struct buffer{
  int lock;
  char (*rxbuf)[BUFFER_SIZE][PACKET_SIZE];
}buffer;

/* Buffer list */
buffer bufferlist[N_BUFFER];

[...]

/* I use this to init structs */
void initializeData() {
  for (int i = 0; i < N_BUFFER; i++) {
    bufferlist[i].lock = 0;
    bufferlist[i].rxbuf = malloc(sizeof(???)); /* ??? <- I don't know what to put here */
  }
}

/* After I insert data */
for (int ibuffer = 0; ibuffer < N_BUFFER; ibuffer++) {
  for (int idata = 0; idata < BUFFER_SIZE; idata++) {
    /* Here I want to pass char array[PACKET_SIZE] */
    int bytes_received = insertData(bufferlist[ibuffer].rxbuf[idata], sizeof(bufferlist[ibuffer].rxbuf[idata]));
    [...]
  }
}

[...]

/* Then write with this */
fwrite(bufferlist[i].rxbuf, sizeof(????), 1, outfile);
```

Please can you help me with this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814773/c-multidimensional-array-allocation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376740/runtime-allocation-of-multidimensional-array ? Yours is possibly a duplicate question.

Comment: @ericbn Thanks but neither was helpful. First needs loop and second is C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your definition of char array in structure

```
char (*rxbuf)[BUFFER_SIZE][PACKET_SIZE];
```

to

```
char rxbuf[BUFFER_SIZE][PACKET_SIZE];
```

With this you already create char array and reserve memory, so no need to `malloc()`.

You can do `fwrite()` as

```
fwrite(bufferlist[i].rxbuf, sizeof(bufferlist[i].rxbuf), 1, outfile);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan! One more question, If I pass bufferlist[0].rxbuf[0] as function parameter, I'm passing char array of PACKET_SIZE this way right?

Answer (score 1):

`char (*rxbuf)[BUFFER_SIZE][PACKET_SIZE];` is only a *single* pointer to an 2D array of sizes BUFFER_SIZE and PACKET_SIZE.

If you want contiguous memory you can either change it to an 2D array

```
char rxbuf[BUFFER_SIZE][PACKET_SIZE];
```

or to a pointer to an array

```
char (*rxbuff)[BUFFER_SIZE] ;
rxbuff = malloc( sizeof( char ) * BUFFER_SIZE * PACKET_SIZE ) ;
```

In both ways the array is accessed in the same way `rxbuff[0][0] = 'a' ;`

Comment: The code example is wrong. the type of the pointer must be 2D: `char (*rxbuf)[BUFFER_SIZE][PACKET_SIZE]`

Comment: @egur Fixed, but actually it should be `char (*rxbuff)[BUFFER_SIZE]`.

Comment: @self In your example, how you write all array without loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
bufferlist[i].rxbuf = malloc(sizeof(*bufferlist[i].rxbuf));
```

That means: Allocate to `bufferlist[i].rxbuf` as much memory as needed by the variable `bufferlist[i].rxbuf` is pointing to.

Following this, the call to `fwrite()` would  be:

```
fwrite(bufferlist[i].rxbuf, sizeof(*bufferlist[i].rxbuf), 1, outfile);
```